# How can I set up a VPN connection in Windows 10?

Tags: network, vpn, router, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 pro x64 and I'm connected over ethernet to my WPA-encrypted adsl home network.
I'm connected to a network adsl, my internet provider is Tim (Release Modem: AGAWI_4.0.7 ). The modem router is downstairs, my pc is on the upper floor.
These are some of the features of my adsl, the basic ones->

*max speed download:* 18609 Kbps

*max speed upload*: 950 Kbps

*IPTV service:* inactive

*Managed TV service:* inactive

*tariff profile:* ADSL Flat

At Lan Interface panel I get the following information->

Indirizzo IP Modem: (an ip address, let's call it 0)

Maschera di sottorete: ( number sequence )

*Stato DHCP*: active

*IP Iniziale DHCP:* (another ip address, let's call it 1)

*IP Finale DHCP:* (another ip address, let's call it 2)

*Stato NAT:* active

*IP Iniziale NAT:* (ip address 1)

*IP Finale NAT:* (ip ddress 2)

In the panel WiFi setting I have the following->

interface Radio: active

Rete Wi-Fi (SSID): (name of my adsl network) (Visibile)

channel Radio (Automatico): 1

Ampiezza di banda (Canale): Auto 20 MHz / 40 MHz

encryption mode: WPA-PSK TKIP-AES 256 bit

encryption key: (password)

Controllo Accesso (access control): disabled

In the panel local access I see that the security authentication is "active".

I'm trying to set up a VPN connection by editing the settings in Windows 10 in the proper configuration panel (see below). My goal is to be more anonymous -when it's possible-  when I surf the internet, see videos, download torrent; I also aim to be more safe when I do e-commerce. That's the reason why I want to convert my pc into a secure system, so I'm trying to configure a VPN network by exploiting my own adsl connection firstly. If I succeed I will try to do that when I'm connected to a public network->

[image]

I put the address of my modem router panel (the one I usually type on the URL bar and then enter by inserting a password; no username is required).
I configured my VPN connection by inserting no username nor password; when I select it and click on "connect" I get the following error->

[image]

I also tried by putting the PPTP (Point to Point Tunnelling Protocol) as VPN type.

How can I configure my VPN connection by using Windows 10 and why I'm having this issue?

Comment: Really not possible to answer this as we know nothing about the VPN you are trying to connect to. It looks like you are trying to VPN to your router from inside your network and that will never work. Tell us about the VPN - where are the 2 VPN end-points - one is your PC, the other is where?

Comment: @JulianKnight is my modem router supposed to be the second endpoint? If yes, the modem router is downstairs, model: AGAWI_4.0.7. My pc is upstairs. I added additional info in my Q right now, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You don't need a VPN between your PC and the router on your internal network. You *might* want a VPN between them across the Internet (e.g. when you are not at home). Or you might want a VPN between your PC and some other network the other side of the Internet (e.g. from PC to work network or to an anonymising public VPN) - which is it?

Comment: I didn't install any VPN service on my pc: I was trying to create a VPN connection to my router from my pc. Now I realize it's not possible, nevertheless I can't understand which the Win 10 VPN function aims to be. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"can't understand which the Win 10 VPN function aims to be"

The Windows 10 VPN allows you to create an encrypted channel between your PC and another end-point, same as any other VPN.

Perhaps the confusion comes from the fact that there are several types of VPN deployment.

The built-in VPN is not that often used, it is typical to find specific VPN client software used instead since vendors try to make the configuration and management simpler.

A VPN end-point can be another PC, a router with VPN termination capabilities (many only have VPN pass-through), a server (maybe a VPS you set up yourself) or a service (AirVPN, Nord, ...).

In each case, the assumption is that you are creating a "tunnel" between one point and another. What you are tunneling through is one or more untrusted networks.

This is why you can't get a tunnel from your PC to the router. Even if the router can act as an end-point, it will assume you only want to do this on the *external* interface and not on the *internal* interface. If you want to test, set up the router and then connect your PC to the outside, maybe using your mobile phone as a "modem".

Answer (score 1):

Integrated home routers typically provide no VPN services, so using Windows 10 or any other VPN client to connect to one will not work.  If the router has a VPN server, you would need to take very specific steps there to set it up before doing anything to the client computer.  After taking these steps, how to configure the computer would be obvious.  Questions about how to accomplish this would be best asked in a StackExchange about computers such as SuperUser (https://superuser.com/)

The more relevant question here is, why do you want to connect to your home router using VPN tunneling?  Is there a specific security goal?  Do you not trust WPA?  Forcing WPA2 with AES would help a lot...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added additional info in my Q: in this case (when I'm connected over my WPA) I aim both to be anonymous and doing payments safely. No, I don't see any VPN service among my modem router configuration tools.

Comment: @robertalrp Using a VPN between your computer and router would not accomplish any of your privacy goals, and it would only protect your data from people that have access to your local area network (who could probably obtain the data using other means).  The virtual network would do very little different than your physical network that it parallels.  **You need to subscribe to a VPN service or use Tor**.